# Evaluating $\lim_{ x \to+ \infty }\left[\frac{[x]}{x}\right]$ and $\lim_{ x \to- \infty }\left[\frac{[x]}{x}\right]$

Tags: limits, fractional-part

Find the limit :
$$\lim_{ x \to+ \infty }\left[\frac{[x]}{x}\right]=?
\\\lim_{ x \to- \infty }\left[\frac{[x]}{x}\right]=?$$

$[x]:$  floor function

I tried:

$[u]∼u :\text{where}  x→∞$

$$\lim_{ x \to+ \infty }\left[\frac{[x]}{x}\right]=\lim_{ x \to+ \infty }\frac{[x]}{x}=1!!!$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For integer $x \ne 0$, we have $[[x]/x] =1$.

For noninteger $x$ such that $|x|>1$, we have $[[x]/x] = \begin{cases}0 & x>1 \\ 1 & x < -1.\end{cases}$

So, $\lim_{x \to \infty} [[x]/x]$ does not exist while $\lim_{x \to -\infty} [[x]/x]=1$.

Comment: Thank you very very  much!!